# Calling a stored procedure with nothing to return using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I understand this is the way we call a stored procedure using Entity Framework.

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType>(
    "mySpName @param1, @param2, @param3",
    new SqlParameter("param1", param1),
    new SqlParameter("param2", param2),
    new SqlParameter("param3", param3)
);
```

But, what if my stored procedure only a has couple of update statements and does not return anything, what should I put instead of `myEntityType`?

Comment: Just for information context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand is obselete in entity framework core 3.1

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You want `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` instead of `SqlQuery`

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    "mySpName @param1, @param2, @param3",
    new SqlParameter("param1", param1),
    new SqlParameter("param2", param2),
    new SqlParameter("param3", param3)
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Matt. Your answer saved lot of time for me.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the below stored procedure which inserts a data in the Students table in the MS SQL database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateStudent
@FirstName Varchar(50),
@LastName Varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Insert into Students(
           [FirstName]
           ,[LastName]
           )
 Values (@FirstName, @LastName)
END
GO
```

but while you are working with entity framework, it will give you a best feature to call procedure with minimum code, kindly take a glance on below program:

```
var context = new CtxEntity(); 

context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CreateStudents @p0, @p1", parameters: new[] { "John", "Alex" });
```

Comment: Posting code is not enough, you should provide some explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, i recently edited code for more explanation with that i explain, coder make sure that architecture having unitOfwork and Repository pattern then this code is worked.

Comment: Please refer above code which has been updated recently and give your feedback @StaceyGirl

Comment: Your post has been un-flagged long time ago, so it is not going to be deleted. There is no way to tell people who -1 it to re-review it though.