# How to execute a stored procedure without returning results in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertTest(@p1 NVARCHAR(50) , @p2 INT)
AS 
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO dbo.Test(Name, Code)
   VALUES ( N'', 0)
END
```

or other

I try with this code:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("InsertTest @p1 , @p2", "a",1);
```

But this leads to error.

How can I run it using `DbContext` ?

Comment: what error? shouldn't you call `ExecuteSqlCommand`? check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219643/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-mvc-by-ef) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264750/how-to-call-stored-procedures-with-entityframework)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a stored procedure with nothing to return using Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990666/calling-a-stored-procedure-with-nothing-to-return-using-entity-framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this.

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
   "InsertTest @p1 , @p2", 
   new SqlParameter("@p1", "a"),
   new SqlParameter("@p2", 1));
```

or

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<object>(
   "exec InsertTest @p1 , @p2", 
   new SqlParameter("@p1", "a"),
   new SqlParameter("@p2", 1)).FirstOrDefault();
```